# How to accept records from a list view without being added in a queue?

Tags: list-view, queue

How to accept records from a list view without being added in a queue?

I have not created queue and have created group in which a particular user is added . Now when that users tries to go that the view  list and tries to accept the record, there is no accept button. I do not want to create a new queue in which this person needs to be added. I just want this user to have the accept button.

Comment: Do you need the user to be able to mass assign cases?

Comment: no i just want user to accept the records from view list without adding the user in a queue.

Comment: There's no configuration-only way of doing this. You could make a custom JavaScript or VF button to do this, if you wanted to, though.

Comment: Can you help me with the code if you have any